# Swift & Facebook login : my UIViewController does not conform to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Even if Facebook tutorial says that there is no need of an header, I had problems while adding FBSDK functionalities via simple importing framework in the .swift files.

So, I followed this tutorial: 
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/
using swift 6.3 SDK Facebook 4.1 SDK

but I got two issues

```
FBLoginViewViewController does not conform to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

Cannot assign a value of type 'FBLoginViewViewController' to a value
of type 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate!'
```

so I can't login, I tried removing the import statements, no change, I also implemented every statement in the appDelegate, everything should be ok, but still...

thanks in advance

```
 //
//  FBLoginViewViewController.swift
//  SocialFBLogin
//
//  Created by XXXX XXXX on 18/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 XXXX XXXX. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit



//@objc(FBLoginViewViewController)
class FBLoginViewViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate     {



@IBOutlet weak var FBLoginPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var FBLoginNameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self
    }

    // Facebook Delegate Methods

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        println("User Logged In")

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                // Do work
            }
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: The tutorial is really nice. I just tried using Facebook iOS SDK 4.2.0 and it doesn't reproduce. I would suggest to update, make sure you've added FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit to your Bridging Header, and try again.

Comment: If you followed all the instructions from the tutorial you don't need any imports. You should have all the imports in the bridging header file.

Also you delegate methods are written correctly. I just replaced them in a working project and I don't receive any errors.

As suggested by @corvuszero try with the latest SDK. The delegate methods could be different from the version you are using and may not match with the example. If you still want to use an older SDK for any reason do not copy/paste the delegate methods, use autocomplete or inspect the FB headers to know the exact declarations.

Answer (score 32):

Sir, I just solved this issue! You gotta conform your viewController to FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate. first, you add it to your protocols like this:

```
class MainView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate 
{
    //Your Code
}
```

To conform to this protocol you have to implement 2 following methods:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    println("User Logged In")
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
}
```

You just copy this code and you'll be fine!

Updated to **Swift 3**

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    print("User Logged In")
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile")
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User Logged Out")
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! The implementation part is important !

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUSSSSSSSSSSSS. You just made the last 3 hours worth while.

Answer (score 3):

By just implementing these methods it worked

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {

        } else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        println("User logged out...")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
            println("User logged in...")
        } else {
            println("User not logged in...")
        }
        let fbLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton! = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
        fbLoginButton.delegate = self
        fbLoginButton.center = self.view.center
        fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move "**func loginButton(...**" and "**func loginButtonDidLogOut(...**" out of "**override func viewDidLoad() {...}**".

Comment: Try to give some explanation with you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the name of methods and delegate have changed

This is my code if it useful for someone

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, LoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        loginButton.center = view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    // MARK: - LoginButtonDelegate
    func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: LoginButton) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with the latest Facebook SDK 4.x version, Xcode 9.0.1 and Swift 4 you need an additional function for the LoginButtonDelegate to work (as you can see if you click on the Delegate protocol and then use CTRL CMD J to jump to its definition):

```
    func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton) -> Bool{
    return true
}
```